# Cannot deploy ASP.NET MVC + React to Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, azure, asp.net-core

I spent almost a day to troubleshoot the problem and still have no result.
Problem: I created a new ASP.NET MVC + React project, NET.core 3.0. When I deploy it to Azure, I got error:

```
HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure
Common solutions to this issue:
The application failed to start
The application started but then stopped
The application started but threw an exception during startup
Troubleshooting steps:
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
For more information visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2028265
```

However, when I create a new project ASP.NET MVC + React project, NET.core 2.2 and deploy it, everything works well. So, I believe, the problem is NET.core 3.0.
Under Development tools -> Extensions, I installed:

```
ASP.NET Core 2.2 (x64) Runtime

ASP.NET Core 3.0 (x64) Runtime

ASP.NET Core 3.0 (x86) Runtime

ASP.NET Core Logging Integration
```

Also, I found that error in logs

```
Application startup exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Key type not specified.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.LoadKey()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.Configure(ApiAuthorizationOptions options)

.....
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at ApplicationProcessingApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Test\Source\Repos\Test\ApplicationProcessingApp\ApplicationProcessingApp\Program.cs:line 16
```

Program.cs:line 16

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
```

Nothing works. I stuck there. I am asking help from the community. Any suggestions will be appreciated. 
Thank you!

UPDATE:
I added that line  to appsettings.json and error above was gone. Right now, my browser returns error 500.

```
"Key": {
      "Type": "Development"
    },
```

Comment: Are you trying to deploy to an Azure We App?

Comment: yes, I am trying to deploy to Azure Web App

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, answer was on the top.
You have to edit you appsettings.json and make you IdentityServer like that

```
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Development"
    },
    "Clients": {
      "ApplicationProcessingApp": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    }
  },
```

I added that part

```
 "Key": {
      "Type": "Development"
    }
```